# Client People Picker - Unable to save value

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, clientpeoplepicker

I'm using the calendar app in SharePoint.

I add a custom person/group field. Autocomplete doesn't work by default.
So, i created a new custom form.

In this custom form, I changed **SharePoint:FormField** to **SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker**.

Now, autocomplete works correctly.

But my problem is, when I save the form, the value of my person field is not saved.

Does anyone know why ?

**EDIT:**

I created a NewForm in SPD2013, i'm calling it "test.aspx"

I open it, and I retrieve my field name "pop" .

```
<tr>
  <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>pop</nobr>
    </H3>
  </td>
  <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="pop" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pop')}"/>
    <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="pop" ControlMode="New"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm changing SharePoint:FormField to SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker like that:

```
<SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker runat="server" id="ff9{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="pop" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff9',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@pop')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff9description{$Pos}" FieldName="pop" ControlMode="New"/>
```

Comment: Please add more details like what code model you are using? Also add your code section.

Comment: I added all my step .

Comment: I have the same issue looks like this is a bug from Microsoft